# Convert ES6 Arrow Function to ES5

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, leaflet

I found a function I can use in a Leaflet project I’m working.  The function is written is ES6 and it works great in both Firefox and Chrome.  However, I need to target IE as well.  In my research I found IE at present don't accept the ES6 Arrow function.  I also I found if the ES6 function was converted to ES5, the function will work in IE.  For days now I tried to convert the following function to ES5 but to no prevail. Some of the solutions I tried were found posted here. Can some please look at my script and let me know what I’m doing wrong.  Also, what is the benefit of ES6 anyway; shorter script?  Thank you in advance.

Here’s the working ES6 script:

```
points.map((p, i) => L.marker(p).bindPopup(`marker${'<strong>' + pointData[i].cityName + '</strong>' + ', ' + '</br>'  + pointData[i].discrip +  "<br /><a class='fancybox-thumb' ' style='width:150px;' rel='fancybox-button'  rel='fancybox-thumb'   data-fancybox-group='"+ pointData[i].popup +"'   title='" + pointData[i].discrip + " '  href='graphic/"+ pointData[i].popup + "' ><img src='graphic/" + pointData[i].popup + "' alt='Image' ' style='width:150px;' ></a>" + "<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'  target='_blank'>Cedellion Report</a>"}`))
.forEach(function(marker) {
    map.addLayer(marker);
    oms.addMarker(marker);
});
```

Here’s my best attempt/guess with no joy.

```
points.map(function(p, i) {
L.marker(p).bindPopup(`marker${'<strong>' + pointData[i].cityName + '</strong>' + ', ' + '</br>'  + pointData[i].discrip +  "<br /><a class='fancybox-thumb' ' style='width:150px;' rel='fancybox-button'  rel='fancybox-thumb'   data-fancybox-group='"+ pointData[i].popup +"'   title='" + pointData[i].discrip + " '  href='graphic/"+ pointData[i].popup + "' ><img src='graphic/" + pointData[i].popup + "' alt='Image' ' style='width:150px;' ></a>" + "<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'  target='_blank'>Cedellion Report</a>"}`)})
.forEach(function(marker) {
map.addLayer(marker);
oms.addMarker(marker);
});
```

Comment: what error do you get? when you run your attempted version in IE?

Comment: The script will crash and in the console I get Invalid character.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you have ES6+ code that you want to make compatible for ES5, to transpile the *syntax*, you can do it automatically with a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/). Plugging in your code gives this result:

```
points.map(function (p, i) {
  return L.marker(p).bindPopup("marker" + ('<strong>' + pointData[i].cityName + '</strong>' + ', ' + '</br>' + pointData[i].discrip + "<br /><a class='fancybox-thumb' ' style='width:150px;' rel='fancybox-button'  rel='fancybox-thumb'   data-fancybox-group='" + pointData[i].popup + "'   title='" + pointData[i].discrip + " '  href='graphic/" + pointData[i].popup + "' ><img src='graphic/" + pointData[i].popup + "' alt='Image' ' style='width:150px;' ></a>" + "<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'  target='_blank'>Cedellion Report</a>"));
}).forEach(function (marker) {
  map.addLayer(marker);
  oms.addMarker(marker);
});
```

You needed to transpile the template literal too - declare strings and concatenate with `+` instead of using `${}` syntax. In addition, you needed to `return` the `L.marker...` from the `.map` callback.

Note that this only transpiles *syntax*, not methods - if you're using ES6+ methods (for example, `Array.prototype.includes`), Babel won't be enough - you'll either need to change the code manually to use an ES5 method (like `indexOf`), or, a better option, include a polyfill ([example](https://polyfill.io/v3/)) to define the ES6+ methods on clients viewing your page.

Answer (score 0):

> If an arrow function is simply returning a single line of code, you
>   can omit the statement brackets and the return keyword. This tells the
>   arrow function to return the statement.

So, just add `return` statement and it should work

for more info:
https://codeburst.io/javascript-understand-arrow-function-syntax-ab4081bba85b